# How to loop through Map of List for specific startDate?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap of the following type

```
HashMap<String,List<Training>> map=new HashMap<String,List<Training>>(); 

Input:
        topicName   startDate   endDate     Trainer  Venue
        css         01-10-2017  11-11-2017  ccc      hyd
        html        01-10-2017  12-11-2017  www      viz
        python      10-10-2017  12-11-2017  www      viz
```

Enter Date: 01-10-2017

The attributes/values to be displayed are like this :

```
Output:
    topicName   startDate   endDate     Trainer  Venue
    css         01-10-2017  11-11-2017  ccc      hyd
    html        01-10-2017  12-11-2017  www      viz
```

I need to retrieve the details of list from getList().What code do i need to write in this method such that when user enters the date i can display output in the desired way as shown above.

```
public List<Training> getList(String fromDate) {

   }

   public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{
       Map<String,List<Training>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Training>>();
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Give me a size ");
       int n = sc.nextInt();
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           String topicName = sc.next();
           //DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
           //Date fromDate = dateFormat.parse(sc.next());
           //Date toDate = dateFormat.parse(sc.next());
           String fromDate = sc.next();
           String toDate = sc.next();
           System.out.println("fromDate********"+fromDate);
           String trainer = sc.next();
           String venue = sc.next();
           List<Training> l1=new ArrayList<Training>();
           l1.add(new Training(topicName,fromDate,toDate,trainer,venue));
           //System.out.println("list********"+l1);
           if(!map.containsKey(fromDate)){
               map.put(fromDate,l1);
           }else{
               map.get(fromDate).add(new Training(topicName,fromDate,toDate,trainer,venue));
           }
       }    
       System.out.println("map********"+map);
   }


@Override
public String toString() {
    return  gettopicName()  + getfromDate() +  gettoDate() +  gettrainer() + getvenue() ;
}
```

Comment: what is the key in your map ?

Comment: fromDate is the key in map

Comment: As an aside referring to your commented-out code: `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated and the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Parsing your dates could be a good idea, but use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from the modern `java.time`API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, `fromDate` is the key for your `Map`. Then, you could simply `get` method which will give you `List<Training>`.

```
return map.get(fromDate);
```

If there are no value for specified key, then it will return `null`.

Comment: I need to retrieve the details of list from getList() which is of type List<Training> so i would be returning the list of rows which matches the date entered by user. how could i do that?

Comment: @Manoj what do you think?? It is very simple. Instead looping the list just  `return` it.

Comment: I am passing Map<String,List<Training>>,userDate as parameters to getList() but i am not able to print the list of values as desired.

Comment: @Manoj If your Map key is `fromDate` and your are comparing same date with Map key, Then, there is no special rule, it won't work. It is not working as expected. Then, you don't have data.

Comment: why iterate and compare all the keys when you can just use the map as intended?:  Training training = map.get(fromDate);

Comment: @slipperyseal Good point. :D I will update. I was thinking some other scenarios  when started writing this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code instead of creating Map based on from Date keep a list of training. If user enter date iterate over the training to filter it.

```
public List<Training> getList(List<Training> trainingList, Date date) {
    List<Training> list = new ArrayList<Training>();
    for( Training training : trainingList ) {
        if( training.getFromDate().getTime() <= date.getTime() &&
                date.getTime() <= training.getToDate().getTime()    ) {
            list.add(training);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

   public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       List<Training> l1=new ArrayList<Training>();
       System.out.println("Give me a size ");
       int n = sc.nextInt();
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           String topicName = sc.next();
           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
           Date fromDate = dateFormat.parse(sc.next());
           Date toDate = dateFormat.parse(sc.next());
           System.out.println("fromDate********"+fromDate);
           String trainer = sc.next();
           String venue = sc.next();
           l1.add(new Training(topicName,fromDate,toDate,trainer,venue));
       }    
       System.out.println("map********"+l1);
   }
```

Comment: `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated and the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead I recommend `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [the modern `java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).